# How to store and echo multiple lines elegantly in bash answer not working?

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, echo, multiline

I tried the solution shown in "How to store and echo multiple lines elegantly in bash?" from May 2, 2010 which was basically to double quote mark the string variable so it recognized the multiple lines in the BLOCK.  Without the quote marks I get the full string dump to a single, wrapping line just like the example in that earlier question.  But when I add the double quote marks around the "$VAR" as the answer says should work, all that I get returned is a double quote followed by  two question marks  "??

This is in a .bash_prompt file called by a .bascrc file that was called by a .bash_profile

All the other elements, and there are many, called by each of these files is working fine.  These include paths, cd, prompt, server, git location, etc. elements.  All I am trying to add is a multi-line statement directing the user on what they might expect and the commands they may need to enter if the Gitlab repository is not actively connected yet because of a server reboot, terminal reboot, etc. since their last active use.

I have tried no quotes, giving a continuous string that amounts to what I want to be five separate lines and that dumps the full string with a line wrap the size of the terminal window.

I have dropped the preceding double quote thinking it might have been left open somewhere earlier. An tried the flip side of dropping the ending double quote.  I have tried single quotes.  I have tried semi-columns at the end of each line I wanted to wrap.  I have tried creating a String variable with the \n lines and echoing the string.

```
read -d '' tell_user <<"BLOCK"
    If you are planning to utilize Gitlab.com repository?, wait until prompts 
    turn colors.
    YOU MAY NEED TO RUN THE COMMAND ssh-add ~/Directory/ed29183 (Dir & #'s 
    faked) 
    THEN AWAIT A REPLY OF Identity added:
    THEN RUN THE COMMAND ssh -T git@gitlab.com
    TO CONNECT TO THE GITLAB REPOSITORY
BLOCK

echo “$tell_user”
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
If you are planning to utilize Gitlab.com repository?, wait until prompts turn colors.
YOU MAY NEED TO RUN THE COMMAND ssh-add ~/Directory/ed29183  
THEN AWAIT A REPLY OF Identity added:
THEN RUN THE COMMAND ssh -T git@gitlab.com
TO CONNECT TO THE GITLAB REPOSITORY
```

OBSERVED RESULT:

```
"??
```

POSSIBLE STEP UP ANSWERS:
You can probably see that I am basically aiming to make sure the local machine is connected to Gitlab and the repository there so that during development activity if connectivity is not there, the user knows it and how to reconnect so they can add and commit any updates, etc.  The prompt modifications that this small snippet of code is part of already tells a user where they are on their own physical machine with the machine name and abbreviated path location and also tells what Git master or branch they are working in.  The very first statement in the snippet that says 'wait until the prompt turns colors' is set up so that it does that when connectivity is there.  I really wanted to consider a stepwise terminal prompting that took user and remote machine inputs to 'test' what the status of connectivity was, ask the user if they wanted and needed it if it wasn't established, and then gave the appropriate branching actions (including time delay handling for speed of connection).  So if someone has a more brilliant answer with more functionality, I am all ears.
But for now I would be happy if I could just get this messaging to present line by line rather than one long string dump.

Comment: Could you indent your code by four spaces so it looks like a normal code block? Right now it's very hard to tell what your code is supposed to look like or if it has problems because it's wrapped like normal text.

Comment: bk2204 Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Did you literall use "smart" quotes?

```
echo “$tell_user”
```

Bash doesn't understand them. Instead use normal double quotes:

```
echo "$tell_user"
```

Works for me:

```
$ echo $tell_user
If you are planning to utilize Gitlab.com repository?, wait until prompts turn colors. YOU MAY NEED TO RUN THE COMMAND ssh-add ~/Directory/ed29183 (Dir & #'s faked) THEN AWAIT A REPLY OF Identity added: THEN RUN THE COMMAND ssh -T git@gitlab.com TO CONNECT TO THE GITLAB REPOSITORY

$ echo "$tell_user"
If you are planning to utilize Gitlab.com repository?, wait until prompts 
    turn colors.
    YOU MAY NEED TO RUN THE COMMAND ssh-add ~/Directory/ed29183 (Dir & #'s 
    faked) 
    THEN AWAIT A REPLY OF Identity added:
    THEN RUN THE COMMAND ssh -T git@gitlab.com
    TO CONNECT TO THE GITLAB REPOSITORY
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is the correct answer. The "??" in the output is a result of bash treating  just part of the UTF-8 representation of the close-fancy-quote as part of the variable name, leaving the remainder as two bytes of invalid UTF-8 that gets printed as "??". See [this apple.se Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296902/what-makes-the-bash-interpreter-utility-interpret-differently-standard-and-smart) for the messy details.

Comment: YES, agree it is answered.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I should have known better.  I am working the local keyboard on my usual MAC laptop but I am coding in a remote mac mini on the network.  I didn't go into the System Preferences, Keyboard, Text on that remote machine to turn uncheck the smart quote box on it.  Dumb but simple error makes all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have quotes around BLOCK ("BLOCK"). Try removing them